# spit JSON object column values into new columns on snowflake ( SQL )

Tags: sql, json, split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to split a json column that has multiple values as shown in the picture below into new columns. I'm using snowflake cause that's where the data is located.

like for example , I want `name`, `predicted`, `level`, `score` all as new column.

[image: JSON column content]

Comment: That data is not JSON. You most likely want to strip apart with SPLIT_TO_PART, SPLIT and TRIM to strip all those hypens and white space. Also you should paste the data to a code block so people don't have to type it in.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So with this CTE to provide the input/data:

```
with data as (
SELECT '---
- trackingId: 0
  name: English
  predicated: 6
  level: higher
  score: 6' as subjects
)
```

lets strip that in parts:

```
select d.*
    ,s.seq
    ,s.value as raw
    ,trim(trim(s.value,'-'),' ') as trimmed 
    ,split(trimmed,':') as parts
    ,trim(parts[0]) as key
    ,trim(parts[1]) as val
    ,iff(key='name', val,null) as name
    ,iff(key='predicated', val,null) as predicated
    ,iff(key='level', val,null) as level
    ,iff(key='score', val,null) as score
from data as d,
table(split_to_table(d.subjects, '\n')) s
where trimmed <> ''
```

gives:

| SUBJECTS | SEQ | RAW | TRIMMED | PARTS | KEY | VAL | NAME | PREDICATED | LEVEL | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| --- - trackingId: 0 name: English predicated: 6 level: higher score: 6 | 1 | - trackingId: 0 | trackingId: 0 | [ "trackingId", " 0" ] | trackingId | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| --- - trackingId: 0 name: English predicated: 6 level: higher score: 6 | 1 | name: English | name: English | [ "name", " English" ] | name | English | English |  |  |  |
| --- - trackingId: 0 name: English predicated: 6 level: higher score: 6 | 1 | predicated: 6 | predicated: 6 | [ "predicated", " 6" ] | predicated | 6 |  | 6 |  |  |
| --- - trackingId: 0 name: English predicated: 6 level: higher score: 6 | 1 | level: higher | level: higher | [ "level", " higher" ] | level | higher |  |  | higher |  |
| --- - trackingId: 0 name: English predicated: 6 level: higher score: 6 | 1 | score: 6 | score: 6 | [ "score", " 6" ] | score | 6 |  |  |  | 6 |

So we can then roll that back up:

```
select seq
    ,max(name) as name
    ,max(predicated) as predicated
    ,max(level) as level
    ,max(score) as score
from (
    select d.*
        ,s.seq
        ,trim(trim(s.value,'-'),' ') as trimmed 
        ,split(trimmed,':') as parts
        ,trim(parts[0]) as key
        ,trim(parts[1]) as val
        ,iff(key='name', val,null) as name
        ,iff(key='predicated', val,null) as predicated
        ,iff(key='level', val,null) as level
        ,iff(key='score', val,null) as score
    from data as d,
    table(split_to_table(d.subjects, '\n')) s
    where trimmed <> ''
)
group by seq;
```

giving:

| SEQ | NAME | PREDICATED | LEVEL | SCORE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | English | 6 | higher | 6 |

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [DOC](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/json-basics-tutorial-flatten.html) to flatten the JSON data into different columns.